# Android Contacts, SMS/MMS, Call logs

Tags: android

I realize this is a duplicate idea from other posts, but it has a slight difference, please read on:

I am effectively trying to extract ALL RAW DATA for android Contacts, SMS, MMS and Call Logs and output each row of data as a JSON object, in a global JSON array.

What I'd like to know, is how do I approach this problem using the Android content providers?

I know I can query each of them. SMS, MMS and Call Logs are straight forward, however, I cannot seem to find a way to do it for the contact data unless I do VCARD, which I DON'T want to do.

To clarify: I need to get EVERY column and its associated value for everything involving Contacts, Call logs, SMS and MMS.

Can anyone help?